# Main DIV CSS not working

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm building a responsive site and the main DIV CSS works when in the desktop size but when I resize to mobile size the CSS in the main DIV stops working. Maybe it has something to do with the @media screen not functioning properly?
I've been stuck at this for two months now and can't find the problem.

**HTML & CSS:**

```css
/* Body styling for browser */
    /* HTML position/height/width */
        html {
            position:relative;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
        }
        
    /* Body height/margin/width/position thing */
        body {
            position:absolute;
            min-width:100%;
            min-height:100%;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        
/* Main */
    /* Main margin */
        @media screen and (min-width: 481px) {
            div#main {
                margin-bottom: 147px;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                position: relative;
                margin-top: 4px;
            }
            
        /* Main text styling paragraph */
            div#main p {
                link-decoration: underline;
                color: #000000;
                font-family: "verdana",geneva,sans-serif;
                margin-top: 4px;
                text-align: left;
            }
/* Main Mobile */
    @media screen and (max-width: 481) {
        /* Main margin mobile */
            div#main {
                margin-bottom: 147px;
                margin-left: 5px;
                margin-right: 5px;
                margin-top: 2px;
                position: relative;
            }
        /* Main text styling paragraph mobile */
            div#main p {
                link-decoration: underline;
                color: #000000;
                margin-top: 4px;
                text-align: left;
                font-family: "verdana",geneva,sans-serif;
            }
    }
/* Other */
    ::selection {
        background: #c1c1c1;
    }
    
    ::-moz-selection {
        background: #c1c1c1;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/ncore/style/style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="/ncore/style/favicon.ico">
    <title>
    <?php
        include "./config.php";
        echo $name;
    ?>
    - Home
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    include 'config.php';
    ?>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="mbar">
            <?php
            include './bar/mbar/mbar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus bibendum maximus est, non gravida ligula pretium ut. Maecenas eget fringilla ligula. Nulla imperdiet velit sit amet egestas faucibus. Donec sodales at nibh ac imperdiet. Donec tristique mollis tempus. Morbi ac orci sed metus facilisis blandit ac ut enim. Donec sit amet blandit tortor. Nunc suscipit, lorem in tempor pulvinar, justo turpis rutrum turpis, ut aliquam nisl velit varius lorem. Nam sollicitudin, turpis in vestibulum vehicula, dui orci auctor tellus, a bibendum arcu mi consequat odio. Aliquam eget maximus mauris. Phasellus sit amet eros quis libero malesuada pulvinar. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi eu placerat turpis. Phasellus aliquet laoreet ipsum, sit amet pellentesque lectus vestibulum in. Nam euismod, lorem vitae vulputate vulputate, est lectus auctor arcu, eu varius neque tortor ac lorem. Donec semper id metus nec egestas.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="cbar">
            <?php 
            include './bar/cbar/cbar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="abar">
            <?php 
            include './bar/abar/abar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id="ebar">
            <?php 
            include './bar/ebar/ebar.php';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've asked this question before but I wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 481) {
```

should be

```
@media screen and (max-width: 481px) {
```

Don't forget your units!

Also, you should make sure your rules don't overlap... max 481px and min 481px will make both rules effective at exactly 481. You should have your max at 1px lower... Or your min at 1px higher.

Comment: Thank you so much! I feel very stupid right now haha. I also set one of the @media screens to 480px.